# error creating a directory for Camera app to store photo

Tags: android, file, camera

Im working on an app that will take a picture, then return it and put it in an imageview.
I was able to get it working when it would return a thumbnail size image. I followed the directions on the android developer page the creates an image file but for some reason it isnt working for me. I have a button that launches a method that calls the createImageFile() before starting the intent. however this method fails and the camera is never even started.

here is my version:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").
                                                format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                       Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    Log.i("storage: ",storageDir.getAbsolutePath());

    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,
                                        ".jpg",storageDir);
    Log.i("filename: ", "afterimage");

    FILENAME = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.i("filename: ", FILENAME);

    return image;
}
```

however my code never makes it past File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,
                                            ".jpg",storageDir) 
becasuse i never see the following Log.i();

I tried creating storageDir with context.getCacheDir() and the camera actually starts but then after taking a photo i am unable to click the check mark and return to the main activity.

Here is the rest of the Activity if necessary:

```
public class Camera extends Activity
{
private final int PICTURE_ACTIVITY_CODE = 1;
String FILENAME;
File f;
Button b;
ImageView image;

@Override
/**
 * onCreate method. Instantiates buttons and textfield
 * and sets a listener for button that launches launchTakePhoto
 * method.
 */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            launchTakePhoto();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * method that finds storage location on devices. Then
 * creates a file and launches an actvitiy for result
 * to retrieve the data later and store it in that file,
 * in that storage space.
 */
private void launchTakePhoto()
{

    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        try
        {
            f = createImageFile();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.i("Error","error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        f = new File(getCacheDir(), FILENAME);
    }
    if (f != null)
    {
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICTURE_ACTIVITY_CODE);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent data)
{

    if ((req == PICTURE_ACTIVITY_CODE)&&(res == RESULT_OK))
    {
            Log.i("res: ", "PASSED");   ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
            Uri uriImage = Uri.fromFile(f);
            iv.setImageURI(uriImage);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help. Ive seen a lot of different possible answers but nothing is working for me so far. I just want to be able to return a full size image and place it in the image holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be best to look at the Android API for image capture as it has recently changed since API 21. Possibly the best way to perform this operation is to open the camera, allow the user to capture the image and use the `onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result)`function defined in: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html to receive the results of the image capture and then set the image viewer to the result. If you are also trying to save the image then try using the file handler process as defined in the Android Documentation at: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

```
 String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```